# Error CL_INVALID_VALUE on simple C++ OpenCL image manipulation program

Tags: c++, opencl, cimg

I'm writing a simple OpenCL program in C++ where i need to flip an input image upside-down, i'm using CImg to read and write image files.
the problem is that even though the program compiles and run without any error, the output file is blank.

Here's the cl kernel code:

```
const sampler_t sampler = CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP_TO_EDGE | CLK_FILTER_NEAREST;

__kernel void img_turn(
    read_only image2d_t I,
    write_only image2d_t O
)
{
    int gid_x = get_global_id(0);
    int gid_y = get_global_id(1);

    int w = get_image_width(I);
    int h = get_image_height(I);

    if (gid_x >= w || gid_y >= h)
        return;
    
    uint4 p = read_imageui(I, sampler, (int2)(gid_x, gid_y));
    write_imageui(O, (int2)(gid_x, h - gid_y), p);
    
}
```

and here's bits of the host code, first the input image (Edited):

```
CImg<unsigned char> img_in(img_file_name);

cl_image_format format = {
    CL_RGBA,
    CL_UNSIGNED_INT8,
};

cl_image_desc desc = {
    .image_type = CL_MEM_OBJECT_IMAGE2D,
    .image_width = (size_t) img_in.width(),
    .image_height = (size_t) img_in.height(),
    .image_row_pitch = 0,
    .image_slice_pitch = 0,
    .num_mip_levels = 0,
    .num_samples = 0,
    .buffer = NULL,
};

cl_mem input_img = clCreateImage(
    context,
    CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR,
    (const cl_image_format *) &format,
    (const cl_image_desc *) &desc,
    img_in.data(),
    &errNum
);
```

the definition of the output image (Edited):

```
CImg<unsigned char> img_out(img_in.width(), img_in.height(), 1, 4);

format = {
    CL_RGBA,
    CL_UNSIGNED_INT8,
};

desc = {
    .image_type = CL_MEM_OBJECT_IMAGE2D,
    .image_width = (size_t) img_out.width(),
    .image_height = (size_t) img_out.height(),
    .image_row_pitch = 0,
    .image_slice_pitch = 0,
    .num_mip_levels = 0,
    .num_samples = 0,
    .buffer = NULL,
};

cl_mem output_img = clCreateImage(
    context,
    CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR,
    (const cl_image_format *) &format,
    (const cl_image_desc *) &desc,
    img_out.data(),
    NULL
);
```

and the last part of the code, where i enqueue the images and run the program (Edited):

```
size_t origins[3] = {0, 0, 0};
size_t region_in[3] = {(size_t) img_in.width(), (size_t) img_in.height(), (size_t) 1};

errNum = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), input_img);
errNum |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), output_img);

size_t global[2] = {(size_t) img_in.width(), (size_t) img_in.height()};
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 2, NULL, global, NULL, 0, NULL, &kernel_event);

errNum = clEnqueueWriteImage(command_queue, input_img, CL_TRUE, origins, region_in, 0, 0, img_in.data(), 0, NULL, NULL);

size_t region_out[3] = {(size_t) img_out.width(), (size_t) img_out.height(), (size_t) 1};
errNum = clEnqueueReadImage(command_queue, output_img, CL_TRUE, origins, region_out, 0, 0, img_out.data(), 0, NULL, NULL);

clWaitForEvents(1, &kernel_event);
img_out.save("./output_img.png");
```

after compiling and running the program the 'output_img.png' image file is created but it's blank: 0Bytes and no data whatsoever when opened with a text editor.

Edit:
So after PeterT's suggestion (and after some corrections of some dumb mistakes i made), the program now seems to be doing something (it executes for 3 seconds), but still produces nothing.

Edit 2:
After a bit of debugging, i pinpointed the problem: `clEnqueueReadImage` returns the error `CL_INVALID_VALUE`, and the [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueReadImage.html) specifies that it returns that error *if the region being read specified by origin and region is out of bounds ...*
But i don't know why. It's the same size of the input image, but `clEnqueueWriteImage` doesn't return any error, even if called with the same parameters.

Edit 3:
The problem has been fixed by Egor's response. But now it doesn't output the wanted result:
Input image:
[image: input image]

Output image:
[image: output image]

Comment: isn't `clCreateImage` with a non-null pointer invalid if `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` is not set?

Comment: @PeterT I remember that i tried to add that, but when i do i get a segmentation fault execution error, so maybe there's something wrong with aome/all the opencl initializations (?)

Comment: @PeterT
You're right, the segmentation fault was because of the way i defined the output CImg object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you create OpenCL image object using `CL_RGBA` format and pass the pointer to `CImg` pixel data. But `CImg` uses "planar" structure to keep the data and the values for color channels are not interleaved (for more information please see [How pixel data are stored with CImg?](http://www.cimg.eu/reference/storage.html)). For example, colored image with alpha channel will be stored in memory as:

`R1R2R3...B1B2B3...G1G2G3...A1A2A3...`

But `CL_RGBA` format implies the interleaved channels for the image: `R1G1B1A1R2G2B2A2R3G3B3A3...`. Therefore, it is necessary to convert the image to `CL_RGBA` format before copying it to the device memory. For example, using following function:

```
struct rgba_pixel {
    unsigned char r;
    unsigned char g;
    unsigned char b;
    unsigned char a;
};

constexpr unsigned int r_channel_idx = 0;
constexpr unsigned int g_channel_idx = 1;
constexpr unsigned int b_channel_idx = 2;
constexpr unsigned int a_channel_idx = 3;

std::vector<rgba_pixel>
convert_cimg_to_rgba_buffer(const cimg_library::CImg<unsigned char>& img) {
    const unsigned int img_height = static_cast<unsigned int>(img.height());
    const unsigned int img_width = static_cast<unsigned int>(img.width());
    const unsigned int number_of_channels = static_cast<unsigned int>(img.spectrum());

    const bool has_r_channel = number_of_channels > r_channel_idx;
    const bool has_g_channel = number_of_channels > g_channel_idx;
    const bool has_b_channel = number_of_channels > b_channel_idx;
    const bool has_a_channel = number_of_channels > a_channel_idx;

    std::vector<rgba_pixel> rgba_buf(static_cast<std::size_t>(img_width) * img_height);
    for (unsigned int y = 0; y < img_height; ++y) {
        for (unsigned int x = 0; x < img_width; ++x) {
            const std::size_t pixel_idx = static_cast<std::size_t>(img_width) * y + x;
            rgba_buf[pixel_idx].r = has_r_channel ? *img.data(x, y, 0, r_channel_idx) : 0;
            rgba_buf[pixel_idx].g = has_g_channel ? *img.data(x, y, 0, g_channel_idx) : 0;
            rgba_buf[pixel_idx].b = has_b_channel ? *img.data(x, y, 0, b_channel_idx) : 0;
            rgba_buf[pixel_idx].a = has_a_channel ? *img.data(x, y, 0, a_channel_idx) : UCHAR_MAX;
        }
    }
    return rgba_buf;
}
```

So the code to copy the image to the device will look like:

```
    size_t origins[3] = { 0, 0, 0 };
    size_t region[3] = { (size_t)img_in.width(), (size_t)img_in.height(), (size_t)1 };
    auto rgba_buf = convert_cimg_to_rgba_buffer(img_in);

    ret = clEnqueueWriteImage(command_queue, input_img, CL_TRUE, origins, region, 0, 0, rgba_buf.data(), 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Also, it will be necessary to convert the output image before saving it. For example using following function:

```
void
copy_rgba_buffer_to_cimg(const std::vector<rgba_pixel>& rgba_buf, cimg_library::CImg<unsigned char>& img) {
    const unsigned int img_height = static_cast<unsigned int>(img.height());
    const unsigned int img_width = static_cast<unsigned int>(img.width());
    const unsigned int number_of_channels = static_cast<unsigned int>(img.spectrum());

    const bool has_r_channel = number_of_channels > r_channel_idx;
    const bool has_g_channel = number_of_channels > g_channel_idx;
    const bool has_b_channel = number_of_channels > b_channel_idx;
    const bool has_a_channel = number_of_channels > a_channel_idx;

    for (unsigned int y = 0; y < img_height; ++y) {
        for (unsigned int x = 0; x < img_width; ++x) {
            const std::size_t pixel_idx = static_cast<std::size_t>(img_width) * y + x;
            if (has_r_channel) *img.data(x, y, 0, r_channel_idx) = rgba_buf[pixel_idx].r;
            if (has_g_channel) *img.data(x, y, 0, g_channel_idx) = rgba_buf[pixel_idx].g;
            if (has_b_channel) *img.data(x, y, 0, b_channel_idx) = rgba_buf[pixel_idx].b;
            if (has_a_channel) *img.data(x, y, 0, a_channel_idx) = rgba_buf[pixel_idx].a;
        }
    }
}
```

And the code to copy the image from the device will look like:

```
    ret = clEnqueueReadImage(command_queue, output_img, CL_TRUE, origins, region, 0, 0, rgba_buf.data(), 0, NULL, NULL);
    copy_rgba_buffer_to_cimg(rgba_buf, img_out);
    img_out.save("./output_img.png");
```

Next, you create the command-queue with default properties. It means that the commands enqueued to the command-queue will be executed in order. Also, you use blocking read and write (`blocking_read` and `blocking_write` flags are set to `CL_TRUE` for `clEnqueueReadImage` and `clEnqueueWriteImage` function calls). In this case the code can work without using OpenCL events to synchronize the execution of the commands. It is just necessary to enqueue the commands in the correct order and use blocking read command to get the result:

```
    size_t origins[3] = { 0, 0, 0 };
    size_t region[3] = { (size_t)img_in.width(), (size_t)img_in.height(), (size_t)1 };
    auto rgba_buf = convert_cimg_to_rgba_buffer(img_in);

    ret = clEnqueueWriteImage(command_queue, input_img, CL_FALSE, origins, region, 0, 0, rgba_buf.data(), 0, NULL, NULL);

    size_t global[2] = { (size_t)img_in.width(), (size_t)img_in.height() };
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 2, NULL, global, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

    ret = clEnqueueReadImage(command_queue, output_img, CL_TRUE, origins, region, 0, 0, rgba_buf.data(), 0, NULL, NULL);
    copy_rgba_buffer_to_cimg(rgba_buf, img_out);
    img_out.save("./output_img.png");
```

Finally, new `y` position for the pixel should be calculated as `get_image_height() - (gid_y + 1)` because `gid_y` is in interval `[0, get_image_height())`. So the kernel code should look like:

```c
    write_imageui(O, (int2)(gid_x, h - gid_y - 1), p);
```

Minor note, if you directly copy the image to the device using `clEnqueueWriteImage` you can omit `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` flag for `clCreateImage` call.

Comment: Thanks man, now the program definetly does something!
But i fear i must ask for help still, because the output image isn't the expected one, i've updated the post to show the images.

Comment: @SauronEvillord, could you please provide or share the current version of the host code? I can take a look at it.

Comment: So, i got back to debugging a bit, and found that `clSetKernelArg` returns the error `CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT`, i missed it the last time...
Anyways, [here's](https://github.com/sauronevillord/opencl-img_turn/blob/main/main.cpp) the code

Comment: According to the [specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.2/docs/man/html/clSetKernelArg.html), it is necessary to pass an address of memory object to `clSetKernelArg`. Also, as I mentioned in the answer, if the command depends on another command it must be queued after the one which it is depended. So `clEnqueueWriteImage` must be called before `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` because the kernel reads the image. I opened the pull request with these changes, please take a look a it.